# Finding the newly added lines of file in SVN

Tags: svn

I am working under svn project, I just want to parse my committed source files and find the newly added lines in the files automatically using hook script, how it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

svn log + svn blame

Try for beginning `svn log -v -q -l 1` inside WC

Comment: Two these commands + some grepping + some logic, placed in post-commit - became hook

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to extract the changed paths by using

```
svnlook changed REPO_PATH
```

you have to use the -r option for the revision (CommittedRev) which is known within the post-Hook script.

The above will give a list of changed files which have to parsed by a script.

If you try to extract the added/modified lines svn blame which will give you the lines which have been modified in the particular revision...

```
svn blame -rCommittedRev:CommittedRev file:///Repository/ | grep "^ CommittedRev "
```

what you can't extract by blame are lines which have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svnlook` to get a diff of the change, and then grep that for lines beginning with a `+` sign, which signifies added lines.

For example, if I want to check to see whether any lines were added which refer to `System.out`, I can use the following pipeline:

```
svnlook diff -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep -E "^\+" | grep -qE "System\.out"
```

And test the return value - 0 means that it found matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

***NO NO NO***

Don't do this using a hook!

When you use a hook script, your user will be stuck waiting for the hook to complete. Instead, use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to handle the task. Jenkins is a build system, but you can have it do things like this and skip the build step entirely. This way, your users won't have to wait for your hook script to complete, and you have a place where you can automatically post the results of the diff you're doing.

BTW, why only newly added lines and not all changes? You can parse the results of an `svn diff` to find all additions, but I would assume you're interested in all changes.

Comment: If it is a quick check (say, up to a few hundred milliseconds), why should the user have to wait for a Jenkins job to notify her asynchronously? A judicious pre-commit hook can make sure the commit doesn't happen in the first place, if it is a problematic commit.

Comment: @Avi - This hook is suppose to check for newly added lines. How are you going to report these lines back to the user? Are you going to email them? Update a webpage? Using Jenkins solves the _reporting problem_ because Jenkins has a place to display the report. Plus, you have the entire history of changes in Jenkins. Plus, it doesn't hold the user while parsing the changes and then trying to email or update a webpage. Hooks are great in communicating directly and immediately to a user. A pre-commit hook prevents the user from doing something wrong. For this, Jenkins is better.

Comment: I'm not sure how you read all this into the question. The question doesn't say he wants a *report* of the added lines, he just wants to find them; I was assuming to do something with them automatically. Not knowing what it is he wants to do with them, I figured I would answer the question (which was how to do it in a hook), rather than tell him he is doing it wrong...